# Sheetjs `!rows` (and `!cols`) property not existing on newly created sheet?

Tags: javascript, sheetjs

Well given the following snippet for sheetjs:

```
const XLSX = require('xlsx');
const workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
const ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet([[1, 2, 3], [4,5,6]]);
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, ws, page);
```

Whenever I try to access a row: `const rows = ws['!rows'];`

it returns `undefined`. Inspecting `ws` shows it also doesn't hold that property. How would I access the row properties (and set for example styles for the first row).

Comment: Are you using the community edition? Because it is the professional edition that apparently allows you to use styles. See: https://sheetjs.com/pro

Answer (score 5):

you need to declare it first, then you can modify width, height

```js
let wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
let ws = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(document.getElementById(id));
ws['!cols'] = [];
ws['!rows'] = [];

ws['!cols'] = [
            {'width' : 30}, // width for col A
            {'width' : 30}, // width for col B
            {'hidden' : true}, ]; // hidding col C
            
ws['!rows'] = [
            {'hpt' : 30},// height for row 1
            {'hpt' : 30}, ]; //height for row 2
            
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'sheet1');
XLSX.writeFile(wb, filename+'.xlsx');
```

Comment: if you want to set height and width dynamically for all cells, just decode range of your work sheet and loop it, 
let range = XLSX.utils.decode_range(ws['!ref']);

Answer (score 2):

!rows and !cols has all the properties you give it. so it's undefined until you set some. The following code sets the first column to be 15 characters wide.

```
ws['!cols'] = [{wch: 15}];
```

more over here: https://github.com/sheetjs/sheetjs#worksheet-object